# Why do have to pull before merging?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have my own local "develop" repository.  I create branches from this using SourceTree GitFlow for every JIRA I work on. I commit to this branch. Then when I am finished, I finish the branch on SourceTree GitFlow which merges the changes from the branch to my development repository.

SourceTree won't let this merge from local branch to local repo if the local repo is behind.  I have to pull changes down from the remote repo first to local repo and then merge my branch.

Why is this?

Comment: I guess because user can make a decision when he is resolving merge conflicts whereas a server can not. So pulling before pushing is made mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your branches are tracked to the remote server in question. This is a feature of git that helps to make sure branches are synced. If you want to understand more about tracking and how to untrack your branches this link might prove useful:

http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/03/09/remote-tracking-branches.html

Also review tracking as explained by the manual. This is always the best decision when you are confused:
https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html